# Establishing this inequality in $L^2$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, inverse-problems

Let $ u \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega) $ where $ \Omega $ is an bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with smooth boundary. If $ 0 \leq h \leq 1 $ is it possible for us to establish the bound
$$4h^2\|h\partial_{x_n}u\|_{L^2}^2 + 4h^2 \|u + hx_nu\|_{L^2}^2 \geq Ch^k \|u\|_{L^2}^2$$

where $ k =1 $. If not, what about the case where $ k \in \mathbb{N} $? Here $ x_n $ is the nth coordinate of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The first step I came up with is to look the bound
$$ 4h^2\|h\partial_{x_n}u\|_{L^2}^2 + 4h^2 \|u + hx_n u\|_{L^2}^2 \geq 4h^2| \langle  h\partial_{x_n}u, u + hx_n u\rangle | $$
using the Cauchy Schwartz inequality. This bound appear in the proof of a Carleman estimate I have been trying to complete.

Comment: Should it be "Carleman estimate", not Careleman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first equation the left hand side has terms of orders $h^2$, $h^3$ and $h^4$. The right hand side has $h^k$.

Let $h \to 0$. In the limit, the left hand side is or order $h^2$ and, due to the inequality, the right hand side must be of order $h^2$ or something that goes to zero faster. That is, $k \ge 2$.